# Iterm2 enable Broadcast Input Shortcut using Applescripts

Tags: applescript, iterm2

Is there a way to enable an Iterm2 instance with two sessions, and enable the Broadcast Input Shortcut capability on both sessions using AppleScripts?.

I have been trying to enable it using at least keystrokes but I was not able to do it.

Here is an example of the code:

```
    tell application "iTerm"
        activate
    end tell
    tell application "iTerm"
        tell current window
            set newWindow to (create tab with default profile)
            tell current session of newWindow
                split horizontally with same profile
            end tell
            tell session 1 of newWindow
                set transparency to 0.5
                write text "clear"
                delay 1         
            end tell
            tell session 2 of newWindow
                set transparency to 0.5
                write text "clear"
                delay 1
            end tell
        end tell
        -- keystroke "L" using {control down, option down, command down, shift down}
    end tell
```

I'm not asking for the code, just asking the command or the right way to solved this.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not current for your case anymore, but for those who surf here through google like I did, as of now the working solution I've found is adding a proper delay before issuing the set shortcut via `System Events`.

Finding the sweet spot for this delay is dependent on how fast your iTerm readies after issuing your window and session commands.

The following is what I have for my multi-ssh session script:

```
tell application "iTerm2"
  delay 4

  tell application "System Events"
    key code 34 using {command down, shift down}
  end tell
end tell
```